# Load XML file on WPF window load

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I have a problem loading XML file on WPF window `onload()` function. If any one can help with some link how to auto load file. I don't want to open dialog box. Thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
void load()
    {
        try
        {
          var xml = File.ReadAllText("XML.xml");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(xml);
            if (true)
            {
                status.Content = "Loaded";
            }
        }
       catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("not");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Better post more detail about your problem so we can help you.

Comment: Just to make sure, you have wired up the Loaded param in the XAML window to run the "load" method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will load your xml file, put this in OnLoad()

```
var xml = File.ReadAllText("my.xml");
var parsed = new XmlDocument();
parsed.LoadXml(xml);
```

put this in try catch of course

here is [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx)

or you can use [XmlDocument.Load](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var parsed = new XmlDocument();
parsed.Load("my.xml");
```